# Swift subclassing ObjC Class, initializer gets recognized selector

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, unrecognized-selector, initializer

The problem is simple. I have a Swift class that subclasses an Objective-C class:

```
class CJGADSearchBannerView: GADSearchBannerView {
    ...
}
```

Then I initialize my class as:

```
let searchBanner = CJGADSearchBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeFluid)
```

The inherited Objective-C class comes from the [GoogleMobileAdsSDK pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK).

It all compiles fine and I can trace the initializer back to its original class in the code:

```
@interface GADSearchBannerView : GADBannerView
```

Then:

```
GAD_SUBCLASSING_RESTRICTED
@interface GADBannerView : UIView

#pragma mark Initialization

/// Initializes and returns a banner view with the specified ad size and origin relative to the
/// banner's superview.
- (instancetype)initWithAdSize:(GADAdSize)adSize origin:(CGPoint)origin;

/// Initializes and returns a banner view with the specified ad size placed at its superview's
/// origin.
- (instancetype)initWithAdSize:(GADAdSize)adSize;
```

But at runtime I get:

```
-[CJGADSearchBannerView initWithAdSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f87cbe88710
```

It used to work, then at some point I built in Xcode 10 and it just broke.

I tried adding `@ObjcMembers` to the new class in case it was an inference issue, I tried deleting `DerivedData` in case it was linking to old code,
I deleted `Pods` and ran `pod install` again, I tried switching between Swift 3 and Swift 4, I tried building in Xcode 9.4 and Xcode 10, but nothing worked.

Comment: I think `GAD_SUBCLASSING_RESTRICTED` is the problem, its a macro that restricts subclassing, although I am not sure how it works

Comment: It does: `#define GAD_SUBCLASSING_RESTRICTED __attribute__((objc_subclassing_restricted))`. I'd say this is a no go.

Comment: Maybe you could achieve the same with a `category`

Comment: That's weird, it used to work and then broke out of nowhere. I don't see why GAD_SUBCLASSING_RESTRICTED would've changed.